# Unitary transformation on vector is equal to the transpose on its orthogonal vector?

Tags: unitary-matrices, quantum-computation, quantum-information

While working on my Quantum course, I have observed that

U|0> = U<sup>T</sup>|1>

for a Unitary matrix U. This is solely based on observations and calculating the matrices. I wish to try and prove this mathematically but haven't got any conclusive results.

Things I tried - using general properties of unitary matrices, I found that

U<sup>T</sup> = ((complex conjugate)U)<sup>-1</sup>

But can't seem to prove my observation.

My question here is

1. Is what I concluded correct for the orthogonal vectors of |0> and |1>?
2. Whether this property can be extended to all orthogonal vectors?
3. How can I prove it mathematically?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What kind of operator (or matrix) is $U$?

Comment: @colt_browning U is a unitary matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation seems to be incorrect: if $U$ is the identity operator (which is certainly unitary), then $U|0\rangle=U^T|1\rangle$ reduces to $|0\rangle=|1\rangle$, which is false.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. However, I am noticing that it is the case in scenarios where U<sup>T</sup> is not equal to conjugate transpose (U). Essentially for non real unitary matrices.

Comment: @VishakhaLall an identity matrix times $e^{i\phi}$ is unitary and non-real for almost all real $\phi$ but the equality still fails. Let's translate it into the language of matrix elements: it basically says that $u_{00}=u_{10}$ and $u_{10}=u_{11}$. Could you give an example?

Comment: In fact, there is only one unitary matrix that satisfies this condition, namely $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ (here I assume $|0\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $|1\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$).